# How to hide all links of specific class with specific href

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm looking for a way to hide all links of class "checkme" that have href equal to "href1" OR "href2" OR "href3" on page load.

Any javascript or jQuery sollution for this?

Comment: do you have a `href4` also or just these3 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with CSS:

```
a.checkme[href='href1'],
a.checkme[href='href2']
{
    display: none;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

http://jsfiddle.net/78zrnnvz/

I appreciate you asked for a js/jq solution, but it seems unnecessary in this situation

Comment: Seems like my sollution - thank you. I had no idea you can target specific hrefs in a such manner with css.

Comment: No worries. Have a look at @transGLUKator's answer too because he points out another useful feature, the [*=], [^=] and [$=] selectors. They are described in the css-tricks links I answered with.

Answer (score 1):

Just some upgrade to CSS solution by ilovecode:

```
a.checkme[href*='href1'],
a.checkme[href*='href2']
{
   display:none;
}
```

This will hide all links, that contain href1 or href2. So it will hide href="http://href1" and href="href1" and href="http://www.href1"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a class, for example 'hide-links' and then add the following CSS to hide the links.

```
.hide-links [href="href1"], .hide-links [href="href2"], .hide-links [href="href3"] { ... }
```

You can then toggle that class, or other similar classes, to hide and show things with-in nested containers with out having a big mess of jquery.